# C#にて非アクティブのプロセスへキー入力したい

Tags: c#

タイトルの通りC#で非アクティブのプロセスへキー入力する方法はありますか？
非アクティブのプロセスをアクティブにしないとできないのでしょうか？？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

相手先プロセスの実装にもよりますが、[`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx)などのメッセージを[`PostMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx)などのAPIを用いて対象ウィンドウに送信すればよいのではないでしょうか。

```
class Program
{
    // イベントを送信するためのWin32 API
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    // 送信するメッセージ
    const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length == 1)
        {
            // 送信側プロセス

            var pid = int.Parse(args[0]);
            Console.WriteLine("Parent PID:{0}", pid);

            // TODO:対象アプリケーションに合わせた形でキーの送信対象のウィンドウハンドルを探す
            var hwnd = Process.GetProcessById(pid).MainWindowHandle;

            for (;;)
            {
                // 現在のプロセスに入力されたアルファベットをそのまま送信する

                var k = Console.ReadKey();

                if (char.IsLetter(k.KeyChar))
                {
                    // 対象ウィンドウにキーダウンメッセージを送信する
                    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr)k.Key, IntPtr.Zero);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            // 終了待機
            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to Exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
        {
            // 受信側プロセス

            // 送信側プロセスを起動する
            Console.WriteLine("Launching Child Process...");
            var p = Process.Start(
                       typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName().Name
                     , Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Child PID:{0}", p.Id);

            // 終了待機
            Console.WriteLine("Hit Enter to Exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: アプリ側の実装に依存するんですね。キーボード入力を完全に再現することはできないのでしょうか？

Comment: @SSDev 何をもって完全とするかは私の決める事ではないので、対象をspy++などで調査してみることをお勧めします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。調査してみます。上記のサンプルで一部のアプリは動作しましたが、動かないアプリもありました。完全というのは少しオーバーですが、キーボードを押下した時と同じ動作をしてくれれば良いです。サンプルコードで一部動作したので一旦解決にします。また質問するかも知れませんが、よろしくお願いします。